# custom snippet returning either JSON or XML

Tags: json, xml, marklogic, marklogic-8

In my custom search options, I have specified a transform-results element.

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <transform-results apply="highlighted-person-summary-snippet" ns="http://ir.abbvie.com/people-db/person-query"
                       at="/ext/lib/person-query.xqy">
    </transform-results>
</options>
```

Is there anyway that the XQuery function that implements the custom snippet can have access to what the accept headers are in the search request and be able to leverage that? I would rather not have two separate options XML files defined with the only difference being that one returns XML while the other one returns JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use [xdmp:get-request-header](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:get-request-header). But if you emit a proper search:match element structure, the REST api should convert that automatically to json if necessary..

HTH!

Comment: This works for me.  Do you know if there is a library somewhere that parses the Accept headers already, like maybe what is used to process the headers before passing to the transform in the $context map?  I am handling the simple cases now, but there could be more complex Accept headers.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I would just assume relatively simple Accept headers. Programmatic calls usually provide simple ones, as they expect a specific response mime. You can use functions like fn:contains, or fn:matches to allow for fuzzy matching..